Is there a way to change the width of the resize handles on a window? Or restart the process "in charge" of resize handles?
Sonoma 14.3.1
I'm trying to resize a window and the handles are insanely small (narrow), like maybe 5 pixels. Which is very small on a 2560x1440 monitor. The weird thing: this is happening on one monitor but not the other. They are identical monitors. It's program-independent.
I have Rectangle window manager already. It's not what I need here.

which answer? I don't see one

Those answers are about the scroll bar
